# is NSDateFormatter dateFromString: supposed to return nil for an invalid string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

According to the class reference, `dateFromString` method returns "A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings". Using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyy"];
NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-04-27T17:45:44.763"];
```

in SDK 3.1.3 returns `nil`, but on SDK 3.2 it returns `2010-01-20 00:00:00 -0300`. Is the 3.2 version the correct behavior?

Comment: I tested it on 3.1.3, it always return nil. And the 3.2 results are really strange, no relationship with the incorrect string.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supposed to return nil. Use SDK 4.